# How to fixed undefined method error in Rails + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

My code + site were previously working and with 0 code changes I started to get this error message in my Heroku logs when trying to query the database:

```
(erb):19:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).
```

I'm not sure where to look for this error because it isn't telling me where to look or what file the error is happening in. If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated!

I have posted the full logs for reference, the app seems to be crashing right away because of this. I am running a Rails server using Postgres with a React front end.

```
2019-05-16T03:18:48.031948+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2019-05-16T03:18:48.031951+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production
2019-05-16T03:18:48.031953+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2019-05-16T03:18:48.031954+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-05-16T03:18:51.847816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 44489 -e production`
2019-05-16T03:18:57.042441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943508+00:00 app[web.1]: (erb):19:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943566+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `eval'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943592+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `result'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943624+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943660+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943682+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943701+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943720+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943741+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943772+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943792+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943811+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:235:in `<class:Blob>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943834+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<main>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943858+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943892+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943916+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943941+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.943966+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944003+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944006+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944007+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944012+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944014+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944015+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944019+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944021+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944024+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944028+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944031+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944035+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944038+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944041+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:334:in `depend_on'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944083+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:85:in `depend_on'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944102+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:246:in `require_dependency'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944107+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944118+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944120+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944122+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944123+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944125+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944126+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944128+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944129+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944131+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944135+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944137+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944138+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944140+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944142+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944143+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944145+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944146+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944150+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944151+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944153+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944154+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944158+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944160+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944164+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944167+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944171+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944174+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944178+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944181+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944184+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944213+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944215+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944220+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944221+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944223+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944227+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944229+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944232+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944235+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944239+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944268+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944270+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944272+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944273+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944275+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944276+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944280+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944282+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944283+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944285+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944288+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944294+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944298+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944300+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944306+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944310+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944312+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944316+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944319+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944322+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944326+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944329+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.944333+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2019-05-16T03:18:56.946482+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2019-05-16T03:18:56.946485+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.3 application starting in production
2019-05-16T03:18:56.946486+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2019-05-16T03:18:56.946488+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-05-16T03:18:57.021770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-05-16T03:18:59.372424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=2d1cd2c7-26c3-4683-811d-cbda8db552dc fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:18:59.663153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=56992e93-e701-4804-a9d7-69c8d8df7d7a fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:19:02.649992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=31ee4ee0-7922-4aa8-a325-8e64ba6df53a fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:19:03.021979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=220e35c1-a291-432a-8d6b-8d29da2767ef fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:19:07.504379+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/users" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=008e3ef2-c32c-47d8-8309-699caa249e63 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:19:07.819506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d73baebd-1589-42e5-924f-5afe337d038d fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.522834+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/campaigns?limit=10&offset=0" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=e9eedb45-dc01-41f0-bbde-8b2ecc0f7961 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.527111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/donations" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=34206172-903b-4e96-a143-8233398054eb fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.552441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBMZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--e302b733d6a303f98f430527e4db7d9e1c7194d0/imaeg10.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=8517b5f3-a6de-4b59-a50e-3fd5df1d844a fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.534909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/campaigns" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b2dd49bb-5ffe-4c69-b4da-b440152c255c fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.558146+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBLdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--c9e2fbcef5f6da29926f88b9a59eafaf2a621902/image8.jpeg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=ad023112-c77f-40a0-aeb2-d27958869cf8 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.560544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBNUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--434e900caca4f34c2e63005cd6820116c07a732c/image12.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b28c7275-2c51-4016-a1b9-a88183564334 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.559299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBGZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--c9c9909537431b859cae12836c80416ea5649eeb/image7.jpeg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=a7b52b07-a196-46ae-a200-4c79571e32cb fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.679112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBNdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--956376570744f0cfdad27f52b232b51ce980f004/image14.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=7826790c-6c3b-4d8d-b4d2-6842d3082719 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.525066+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/users" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=3136154e-d953-424c-8460-956157999cb3 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.554648+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--b51c526a014de8d76bb5d90f35796fb2eae84886/image3.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=3caa2f7a-8db5-4592-b8f9-be25e2af6304 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.562032+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBMUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--5c47228f800d55ab9ec19b608f3222382f67280a/image9.jpeg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=176b645d-0eea-416b-8f7b-6f8efdf769c4 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.679591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--2e0ed771252e549303c16fe6bfd23cc0b44623ac/image4.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=08371d3f-fe83-48c3-88ff-d6e911366cb7 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.670224+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBNQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--76604889b9eb7c143ae9ab78a7fc1243783a77b7/image11.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=17b2b861-0343-4a9a-8bad-ffabd1bdc9e8 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:21:18.677029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBOQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ecd1de1a884d5248751e826ea51b0b6053f36c63/image15.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=28628a35-65f1-4247-944e-453595204b11 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.803733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/campaigns?limit=10&offset=0" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d6612341-e2da-48e2-a69d-8a2f77920d8f fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.802351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/donations" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=49819d09-b169-48c1-958b-0ac1ece45e2c fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.801217+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/users" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d74d9cb1-ab8f-45b2-857c-a52d5afe680c fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.836605+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBNQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--76604889b9eb7c143ae9ab78a7fc1243783a77b7/image11.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=c4cf28a2-f071-48df-98bd-67fa4d14c9ee fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.807718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/v1/campaigns" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=4d22425b-0686-4702-9b67-da66846e67d6 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.835121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBGZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--c9c9909537431b859cae12836c80416ea5649eeb/image7.jpeg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5d8e4d55-54af-45d6-b221-8f4b62a5d42b fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.957398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBNdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--956376570744f0cfdad27f52b232b51ce980f004/image14.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=6ceed2db-cbe1-4c35-83f9-1b86b43f1435 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.834407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBMZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--e302b733d6a303f98f430527e4db7d9e1c7194d0/imaeg10.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=fd8bb5a6-1c76-4dfe-b5d6-9139e4ed2ae8 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.945770+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBMUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--5c47228f800d55ab9ec19b608f3222382f67280a/image9.jpeg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=c8654612-7345-46df-a9ce-9d147a12ea2f fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.937624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBNUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--434e900caca4f34c2e63005cd6820116c07a732c/image12.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f58d4b84-7da2-47b7-ac31-afab5ad7bbeb fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.948654+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--2e0ed771252e549303c16fe6bfd23cc0b44623ac/image4.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=8dfb2fa6-5768-45ae-aa5c-8fbb63eae45a fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.837688+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBLdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--c9e2fbcef5f6da29926f88b9a59eafaf2a621902/image8.jpeg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d728ad22-472c-4047-827f-917ab6889b0b fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.824566+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--b51c526a014de8d76bb5d90f35796fb2eae84886/image3.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=092dad6d-c47e-4db7-bd41-7714563669f2 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-05-16T03:29:13.836115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBOQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--ecd1de1a884d5248751e826ea51b0b6053f36c63/image15.jpg" host=access-health-api.herokuapp.com request_id=c5d50bb9-e35c-4c64-9cdd-4d583f9a0dd4 fwd="68.198.112.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is coming from Embedded Ruby. Is there a YAML configuration file with ERB tags `<%= %>` that is trying to access a key of a `nil` hash?

```
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `eval'
```

Comment: I haven't changed any YAML files since it has started breaking, I just checked the database.yml and the storage.yml files (those are the only ones I edited originally) and they look the same. What would you do to debug a YAML file?

Comment: It was just a guess. What was the last version that worked? Find out the git commit and then run a diff. `git diff $lastCommitThatWorked`

Comment: I have tried reverting back to the commit where it was working and I receive the same error. With the reverted code the back end hasn't changed, only the front end.

Comment: It could be a problem with a dependency. Have any of the gems you're using recently upgraded?

Comment: I have bundle installed, that should fix that issue right?

Locally I have been getting another error that I've googled to no avail: 


*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Attachment::ActiveStorage::Blob

Answer (score -1):

I just solved possibly the same problem. Turns out, I didn't have a Rails master key set in Heroku. Here's the info that worked for me:

> Before continuing on we'll take a moment to do an absolutely essential step to ensure Active Storage works with Heroku. Heroku will only be able to unencrypt your credentials.yml.enc if we add our master key (which can be found in config/master.key). However, the master key is gitignored for good reason. Do not check this file into git. We can use the heroku command line to secretly add the key to our heroku config.
>
> `$ heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<your-master-key-here>`
>
> If you do not do this Active Storage won't work on Heroku and will cause a ton of unhelpful errors.

Comment: Please [don't repeat the same answer over and over for multiple questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256849/354577).